# How to create Stripe customers?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I need to create a Stripe customer and subscribe them to a plan.
I looked into Stripe.js and it seems while you can obtain tokens, it does not offer anything beyond that. There are libraries available for node, for PHP, but why not for Javascript ? I also looked at their API docs, and while there is a curl endpoint for doing this,

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
   -d "description=Customer for test@example.com" \
   -d card=tok_14RLND2eZvKYlo2C6poIibG2
```

I cant figure out how the -u parameter would translate to a POST request via JS. Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: a javascript only solution would mean you have to expose your keys which wouldn't be very smart

Comment: Right. That makes sense. I had a sense it had to be a security issue. Thanks for validating. If you post this comment as a answer,i can accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, anything that could result in a charge requires server-side code (for security purposes). But if you want to give the appearance of being a client-side-only solution, you could use Ajax to pass the token to your PHP script where the server-side request is made.

Hope that helps!
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.